# How to make "conda" installer look for "PyPi" packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was trying to use [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#managing-packages) package manager to install my Python packages. Recently I encountered that many of the packages that I required were not present in the Anaconda.org repository, and I had to pip install them. Ref: [github issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/created_by/orsenthil)

Is there a way to [add a channel](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/custom-channels.html) to Anaconda that will enable it to look for All PyPi packages so that I can use "conda" completely instead of switching over to pip every now and then

Comment: conda skeleton pypi will create conda recipe for those packages available for PyPi. Then you can conda install with this conda recipe, http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html#conda-build-skeleton

Comment: Thank you, @TianZhang. If there is no other way, you could mention this in the answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to conda skeleton, you can first run

```
conda skeleton pypi package
```

It will generate conda recipe for that package if it is available on PyPi, then

```
conda build package
conda install --use-local package
```

It will install the package

Enjoy !