# Can't find correct directory for Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, conda

I'm using a docker container with from base image `jupyter/tensorflow-notebook` While trying to run a command [kale](https://github.com/kubeflow-kale/kale) , it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/kale", line 7, in <module>
    from kale.command_line import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kale/command_line.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nbformat as nb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ipython_genutils import py3compat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipython_genutils'
```

While trying to install `ipython_genutils` using `pip install ipython_genutils`, it says

`Requirement already satisfied: ipython_genutils in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.2.0)`

The same can be confirmed with `conda list` which does among others show

`ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge`

However pip list doesn't show the same. My question is how can I make kale know to find the module in the correct directory?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install ipython_genutils`?

Answer (score 3):

You described three different python environments-

```
Requirement already satisfied: ipython_genutils in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nbformat/__init__.py"
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
```

The first is a conda python3.7 environment. The second is a user-global python3.6 environment. The third is inside conda (am not an expert, could be the first one and the third are the same)

So "kale" is using python3.6, but ipython_genutils is installed in conda. I would uninistall kale using pip (python3.6 -m pip - have to make sure the pip for the correct environment!), and reinstall it with conda.

Comment: Conda doesn't have it in its repo:
`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - kubeflow-kale

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar.
`

Comment: Trying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209848/how-to-make-conda-installer-look-for-pypi-packages solution for the same. I'll update here if I still encounter the same issue. BTW your explanation is on point. I too had a same feeling but being new to the environment didn't allow me to put my question in any better way.

Comment: Manually building the PyPi package to conda isn't going well because of some error `Error message: Invalid version '>=1.4,': cannot join single expression` Is there a way to use everything the other way round, i.e. remove conda environment completely and use user-global python3.6 environment with pip ?

Comment: did you try `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7 -m pip install kubeflow-kale`? (or conda has a `conda run pip if I remember correctly).